# Generate entities with JPA - with java 8 time library/equals & toString methods?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jpa

I'm using Eclipse+JPA to generate entities from my database. It all works just fine, except for two things

- All my time fields in the database are being generated as "Date" objects. Is there a way to generate them as `LocalDateTime` objects instead?
- Is there a way to get the entities generated complete with `equals()` and `toString()` methods that *do not* contain foreign keys? This is to avoid getting circular dependencies and a stackoverflow error whenever I print out my object.

Comment: It is not customary to include `equals` methods on entities, as their identities are distinct.

Comment: @chrylis You're correct that you shouldn't need it in production code. But when I write my junits, I'd like to be able to test that my entity that I've created is equal to an expected entity

Comment: What version of JPA are you using? Implementation?

Comment: Hibernate, and spring version 4.3.4, and javax.persistence 2.2